# Where is the download for the dotnet GMail APIs?

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client, gmail-api

The link specified: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Gmail_API points to an outdated page, and the new reference on that page does not have it either: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/

I don't see it on Nuget either.

Comment: Not sure this is a "recommendation" here, these are official client libraries for the gmail api that were missing.  Seems pretty target question/issue for the "gmail-api" tag even if it is an "off-site resource".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated]
It's finally ready now and linked from the downloads page like you'd expect:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads

That links to the .NET client docs:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/gmail/v1

Which has pointers to the libraries in NuGet.

Comment: That was it! I did try messing with URLs too, but looks like I missed it.